# extract dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss UTC regex (octoparse)

Tags: regex

i have the following string I need to convert with a regex function:

```
02-03-2018 00:02:20 UTC
```

I need to have the following output: `02-03-2018`

I tried : `\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}`

but I get:

[image: output]

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are matching date, but you have empty string in `replace with` so the date is removed. [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mrNnea/1)

Comment: So what should i specify in replace with? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Is captures an option with this tool... if yes, then you can use the regex

`^.*?(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}).*$` basically matching the entire string, begin to end.

And replace with: `$1` which would be value of the first capture, i.e. the value in brackets.

Example: https://regex101.com/r/KTLKXS/1